# How to solve this?? Error in [<-.data.frame: new columns would leave holes after existing columns

Tags: r

Below is my code. This is a part of my shiny app. Whenever i am trying to run the app an error appears
**Error in [<-.data.frame: new columns would leave holes after existing columns**

> ```
>     not_found[,4:ncol(results)] <- NA
>     colnames(not_found) <- colnames(results)    
>         
>     results <- rbind(results, not_found)
>     
>     #Remove columns that are not useful
>     drop <- grepl("(original|super|_v2_|wib|necta|cia|_at|population|is_micro|dma|type_id|region|zip)",
>  colnames(results), ignore.case = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
>    
>     results <- results[, drop == FALSE]
>     
>     results
>     
> })
>
>
> output$contents <- renderTable({
>     req(mydata())
>     mydata()
>     
> })
>
> output$response <- renderTable({
>     myresponse()
>     
> })
> ```

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: not_found[,4:ncol(results)] <- NA    is there any problem with this line